# How to I solve CA1009-warnings (declare event handlers correctly) with TypedEventHandler?

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp

In an UWP application I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public event TypedEventHandler<MyClass, EventArgs> MyEvent;
}
```

When I run code analysis this code gives me two warnings:

**CA1009** Declare the second parameter of 'TypedEventHandler' as an EventArgs, or an instance of a type that extends EventArgs, named 'e'.

**CA1009** Declare the first parameter of 'TypedEventHandler' as an object named 'sender'.

How do I solve these issues? I've read the documentation about [CA1009](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182133.aspx) but it doesn't give me any hint.

Answer (score 1):

For the classic .NET pattern, your class should derive from `EventArgs` to fix the first warning, although that won't work for a Windows Runtime component. You should just ignore the warning.

For the classic .NET pattern, the first type should be `Object` but for newer designs (like WinRT) you should also ignore the second warning.